# I would like to make new column extracting values from column names and get values from row

Tags: r

[image]

This is my original data. I would like to make this data to that type of data in R

[image]

I am not sure how to do that. If I'll have to make a new dataset that is also okay.

Comment: Please use `dput(data)` in `R` to provide us with a data in a neat format.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through the combination of the `tidyr::pivot_longer` and `dplyr::case_when` function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Name = c("Sam", "Nick", "John"),
                 Sem1 = c(52, 67, 35),
                 Sem2 = c(89, 57, 26),
                 Sem3 = c(75, 26, 74))

df <- df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!Name, names_to = "Semester", values_to = "Marks") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Semester = dplyr::case_when(
    
    Semester == "Sem1" ~ 1,
    Semester == "Sem2" ~ 2,
    Semester == "Sem3" ~ 3
  ))
```

**RESULT:**

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  Name  Semester Marks
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Sam          1    52
2 Sam          2    89
3 Sam          3    75
4 Nick         1    67
5 Nick         2    57
6 Nick         3    26
7 John         1    35
8 John         2    26
9 John         3    74
```